# ios UI. Where to put UI elments?

Tags: ios, user-interface

How to create this kind of app design?
I think all should be a big UITableView with custom UITableViewCell elements (red blocks)?

[image: app design]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with UITableViewCell but it will be too big cell , if this Cell is repeating than you have to Use UITableview with CustomCell , OtherWise Use UiscrollView put your elements inside ScrollView and Set it's ContentSize Accordingly.

Comment: I mean to put all red blocks in 6 separate cells with 6 xib. Because I think it is very difficult to put all in one big scrollView, to much elements in one View.

Answer (score 0):

Use more than 6. It can be done with a table view with sections, but your red boxes group too much into some cells. For example, your cell 6 should really be 4 cells (one for each part separated by a line and with an arrow telling the user they can select it to see more). This applies to all of your red boxes, so where you show 6 cells I'd actually be thinking of having 16, probably of around 9 different custom types for your different content styles (images, images with text, headings, bold and faded, etc). You need to look through what's there and find:

1. Each separate part that users want to tap on to go somewhere else
2. Similar parts that can be done using the same cell just configured with different data